# How to integrate indicator function to calculate a volume? Example task: Calculating the volume of an n-dim. sphere

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm currently having quite a problem understanding the integration of indicator functions.
We have hardly worked on the topic and only need the indicator function to assign a volume to bounded sets.

Let $A$ be a bounded set and $C$ be a cuboid with $A\subset C$.
$A$ is Jordan-measurable if and only if the indicator function $\chi_A$ is integrable on $C$.
Then the Volume of $A$ is given by $F(A)=\int \limits_{C}^{}\chi_A$.

Goal:

I want to calculate the volume of a closed $n$-dimensional sphere $S_n(r):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\, ||x||\leq r\}$ with $r>0$ and the centre $0$.

Preperation:
I have problems to understand how I integrate a indicator function. Many instructions online are related to probabilty theory.

The only example I have is for $n=2$ and $r=1$ so that $A:=S_2(1)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n|\, x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$:

To calculte $\chi_A$ over a bounded set, one needs to continue the function over a cuboid $C$ with $A\subset C$.
In our case $C=[-1,1]^2$ ensures that $A\subset C$.

Using the Fubini theorem:

$$F(A)=\int \limits_{C}^{}\chi_A=\int \limits_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]}^{}\chi_A=\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\chi_A \, dy \, dx$$

Now in the sample solution it is stated: $\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\chi_A\, dy=2\sqrt{1-x^2}$
I don't understand this step because $\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\chi_A\, dy=[y]_{-1}^1=2$

$F(A)=F(S_2(1))=\pi$ is the result.

Now I want to calculate the Volume of $S:=S_n(r)$. First I can define the cuboid as $C:=[-r,r]^n$ so that $s\subset C$

$$F(S)=\int \limits_{C}^{}\chi_A=\int \limits_{[-r,r]^n}^{}\chi_S=\int \limits_{-r}^{r}...\int \limits_{-r}^{r}\chi_S \, dx_n \, dx_1$$

Statement: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ with $n\geq2$ be arbitrary then $F(S_n(r))=r^nF(S_n(1))=r^n\pi$

By induction:

$n=2$:

$$F(S)=\int \limits_{[-r,r]^2}^{}\chi_S=\int \limits_{-r}^{r}\int \limits_{-r}^{r}\chi_S dx_2 dx_1=\int \limits_{-r}^{r}[x_2]_{-r}^r dx_1=\int \limits_{-r}^{r}2r dx_1$$

Again, I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Fubini the technique is usually to make the limit of first variable dependent on the other, and then to find the limit for the second variable we can “ignore” the first.

The condition for (x,y) be in the sphere (so the indicator function is 1) is $$x^2+ y^2 \leq 1 \implies -\sqrt{x^2-1} \leq y \leq \sqrt{x^2-1},  -1 \leq x \leq 1$$
$$ \int_{-1}^1dx\int_{-\sqrt{x^2-1}}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dy$$ ...

Comment: So $\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\chi_A\, dy=[y]_{-1}^1=2$ is wrong because $y(x)$ depends on $x$?

Comment: @cedric Yes, if you just integrate over $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ then that would give you the area of that square